# Depth Image Processing OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, depth

I have a depth image of a cow's body surface  using Kinect Sensor. I want to identify the hook bones in the image and use them as reference points for subsequent processing. How can I find the bumps of the hook bones and spinal ridge Just like the sample image below (Image 2).
(It's easy to find these points with MATLAB)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: With which toolbox or command did you find them in Matlab?

Comment: imregionalmax function.

Comment: There are plenty of codes in github that implemented regional maxima method in python or c++, search them and use.

Comment: Isn't it better to use machine learning algorithms?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know such method that works better for this problem. GLCM features may help but I'm not sure.